# Rabbi Matis Blum Torah Lodaas Sheets Online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, parsha-torah-portion, publications

I've been trying to find copies of Rabbi Blum *zatza"l*'s Torah Lodaas Parsha Sheets online, but I can't seem to find them. Are they documented anywhere, or am I out of luck?

Comment: TorahLodaas@gmail.com

Comment: Also the majority of the sheets have been compiled into Sefarim that can be purchased at most Sefarim stores. They are called Torah L'Daas.

Answer (score 2):

https://chat.whatsapp.com/FoEUNgaLhIqLJVdDOArLJG

Rabbi Blums sefer torah lodaas is learnt 2x a week on this chat

Answer (score 1):

Hello my name is Lazer Hoffmann

While going thru old stuff from my father z"l I found a collection of almost all the Torah Ladaas weekly publications from the years 1989 - 2000. I have no need for them and am willing to sell them or give them away. I also have a collection of many other publication that I don't need.

If you're interested to get them contact me at lazerhoff@gmail.com